# Set "Allowed HTTP Methods" in the cache behavior using CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cloudformation

Is there any way to set the "Allowed HTTP Methods" to "GET, HEAD, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS" using CloudFormation? I have a cache behavior described in my stack but by default it only accepts GET and HEAD but and I need it to accept POST method. How do I do that using CloudFormation?

Answer (score 0):

As this property is not available in the [CacheBehavior type](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-cachebehavior.html#cfn-cloudfront-cachebehavior-forwardedvalues), i believe it is not available to be set through CloudFormation. You might set it using the API and a [CustomResource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cfn-customresource.html), but that might be complex. See [these examples](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cfn-custom-resource-examples) for how that approach would go.

Comment: A custom resource really is a complex thing only to set this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to do it like this:

```
CacheBehavior:
  TargetOriginId: ***-***-***
  ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
  MinTTL: 0
  AllowedMethods: [DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT]
  CachedMethods: [HEAD, GET]
  Compress: true
  ForwardedValues:
    Headers: ['*']
    QueryString: true
    Cookies:
      Forward: all
```